# React highcharts, show legends as bar

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart, react-highcharts

This code is displaying the legends as circle, <<<

I want to display the legends as bar as shown in the below image.

My requirement is the legends should be displayed as bar instead of circles

[image]

Here you can take a look at my code:

```
Highcharts.chart('flow', {
        chart: {
          plotBackgroundColor: null,
          plotBorderWidth: null,
          plotShadow: false,
          type: 'pie',
          width: 500,
          height: 260,
          style:{
            marginBottom:"30px"
          }
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Flow',
          x: 90,
          y: 80,
          style:{
            fontSize:"25px",
            fontWeight:600
          }
        },
        tooltip: {
          pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
          pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              distance:-30,
              color:'white',
              fontSize:'9px',
              format: '{point.percentage:.1f} %',
              style: {
                textOutline: false 
              }
            },
            showInLegend: true
          }
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
    legend: {
      align: 'right',
      layout: 'vertical',
      verticalAlign: 'middle', 
      x: -100,
      y: 90,
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Flow',
      colorByPoint: true,
      data: [{
        name: 'Owned',
        y: 74,
        color:"#f5990f"
      },{
        name: 'Invited',
        y: 36,
        color:"#fce61e"
      }]
    }]
});
```

Highcharts.chart('flow', {
        chart: {
          plotBackgroundColor: null,
          plotBorderWidth: null,
          plotShadow: false,
          type: 'pie',
          width: 500,
          height: 260,
          style:{
            marginBottom:"30px"
          }
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Flow',
          x: 90,
          y: 80,
          style:{
            fontSize:"25px",
            fontWeight:600
          }
        },
        tooltip: {
          pointFormat: '{series.name}: **{point.percentage:.1f}%**'
        },
        plotOptions: {
          pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              distance:-30,
              color:'white',
              fontSize:'9px',
              format: '{point.percentage:.1f} %',
              style: {
                textOutline: false 
              }
            },
            showInLegend: true
          }
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
        legend: {
          align: 'right',
          layout: 'vertical',
          verticalAlign: 'middle', 
          x: -100,
          y: 90,
        },
        series: [{
          name: 'Flow',
          colorByPoint: true,
          data: [{
            name: 'Owned',
            y: 74,
            color:"#f5990f"
          },{
            name: 'Invited',
            y: 36,
            color:"#fce61e"
          }]
        }]
    });

I would appreciate any help that I can get to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Saurabh Mishra and welcome to StackOverflow. Your question needs editing as some text is hidden and your code is not formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create additional `column` charts and place them under the legend items:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var columnChart1 = Highcharts.chart("columnChart1", columnChartOptions),
                columnChart2,
                xPos = this.legend.group.translateX,
                yPos = this.legend.group.translateY,
                items = this.legend.allItems;

            columnChartOptions.series[0].data = [76];
            columnChartOptions.series[0].color = 'yellow';
            columnChart2 = Highcharts.chart("columnChart2", columnChartOptions);

            columnChart1.renderTo.style.top = yPos + 50 + 15 + items[0]._legendItemPos[1] + 'px';
            columnChart1.renderTo.style.left = xPos + 'px';

            columnChart2.renderTo.style.top = yPos + 50 + 15 + items[1]._legendItemPos[1] + 'px';
            columnChart2.renderTo.style.left = xPos + 'px';
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wsc4be92/